# Import ribbon customization only into MS Word 2010 without the QAT?

Tags: import, ms-word, customization, ribbon

Can I import my ribbon customizations into Word 2010, without replacing my Quick Access Toolbar?  I tried editing the XML.  I copied the QAT code I was happy with from Machine 1 and replaced Machine 2's integrated customization file's QAT section with what was in the clipboard.  (Obviously I exported a back-up first.)  Unfortunately when I tried importing this hybrid customization into Machine 1's MS Word, the QAT was reset to the newborn version with no customizations.

I figured the QAT code started with `<mso:qat>` and ended with `</mso:qat>`.

Comment: It's not clear to which XML you're referring? I get the impression this is the personal file (not available in 2007) that's generated when the user changes the QAT - and not "RibbonXML"? If yes, I suspect it would be possible, with some editing, and that would be more a topic for an end-user venue. My recommendation, though, would be to take the time/trouble to "translate" what you have to Ribbon XML, save it in a dotm file, together with any macros that may be associated with the customizations. Then you can copy the template and it can be loaded as an "add-in" on any machine you like...

Comment: I'm trying to pull together my QAT customizations from one machine and my ribbon customizations from another.